# For loop doesn't seem to be executing

Tags: java, for-loop, try-catch, filewriter

When I run this only one line is written to the file even when the ArrayList hash has more than one value.

I have tried removing fileWriter.close but then nothing is written to the file.

```
for (int i = 0; i < hash.size(); i++) {
    String fileContent = hash.get(i);
    FileWriter fileWriter;
    try {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(OutputPath);
        fileWriter.write(fileContent);
        fileWriter.write("/n");
        fileWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Form.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I would like this to write each value of the array to its own line in the file.

Answer (score 2):

You are continuously opening and closing the file; you should open it once before your loop (and close it once after). However, it is not necessary to manually close the file at all if you use the [`try-with-Resources` close statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) (which is what I would *prefer*). And a newline is `\n` (but that's also OS specific) so I would use `System.lineSeparator()`. Finally, there is no reason to use an explicit array index here so I would use a [`for-each` loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html). Like,

```
try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(OutputPath)) {
  for (String fileContent : hash) {
    fileWriter.write(fileContent);
    fileWriter.write(System.lineSeparator());
  }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Form.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you keep overwriting the same file. Every time you execute one iteration of the loop, you open the file and overwrite its contents.

Move your `for` loop inside the try/catch between the opening and closing of the file as follows:

```
FileWriter fileWriter;
try {
    // open the file once
    fileWriter = new FileWriter(OutputPath);

    // loop through your items, writing each one to the file
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.size(); i++) {
        String fileContent = hash.get(i);
        fileWriter.write(fileContent);
        fileWriter.write("/n");
    }

    // close the file once
    fileWriter.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {   
    Logger.getLogger(Form.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Prefer `try-with-Resources`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch totally agreed - just trying to limit the scope of the fix.

Answer (score 0):

use `fileWriter = new FileWriter(OutputPath, true);`. This will make append to true. So your file content will not be overridden in the for loop

or move the `fileWriter = new FileWriter(OutputPath);` out from the `for loop`